# How to restore MS SQL logon password

Tags: passwords, services, sql

I am running MS SQL Server. The SQLSERVICE logon password was changed incorrectly and now I'm getting a logon failure warning when starting it.

Is there any way to restore previous used password?

Comment: What kind of SQL server do you use?

Comment: MS SQL Server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't restore a previously used password for a service.  The service start only holds the current password - which may or may not be the same as the SA password

If your service is starting in the context of a user (as opposed to netowrk service, local system etc), then your only real choices are:

**Use local system accounts** - 
This may not suit your needs - you already have auser starting this service, so at a guess, there was probably a reason why you arent using these.

**Reset the Users Password** - Great if this user is onl;y in use for this service.  If the user is also used as the start account for multiple services or is used in other applications, you will need to update all other references to this account

**Create a new user** - assign it log on as service rights (local security policy) and start the service in that users context (remember to grant the user all needed file/database rights)

**Get the old user password** - check your email, any old documentation/notebooks, brute force if really needed

Outside of this, there isn't a vast amount you can do... possibly try the SA password (if you know it).

Hope this helps.